# Htaccess for redirect of non-existing subpages

Tags: .htaccess

For a website I just relaunched, I would like a htaccess redirect catching all non-existing subpages under `/blog/` to just point to `/blog/` and not a 404 (so `/blog/old-page/` would just redirect to `/blog/`). It's important however that the still existing subpages (such as `/blog/new-page/`) aren't redirected. It's also best if this can be in the root htaccess file (not in the subfolder). I feel like I've tried everything, but can't find a solution for this without making redirects for every single old subpage (there are >100)!
I hope someone can help.

Comment: Why can't you simply use the `ErrorDocument` directive? That is the most common approach for redirecting requests to resources that result in a erroneous http state. See the documentation for examples.

Comment: How are pages being routed? How are requests for `/blog/new-page/` handled? Do you have a front-controller of some kind? Or do these URLs map directly to physical files?

Comment: However, what you are proposing is no better for SEO or users, than a "custom" 404. A many to one redirect like that is likely to be seen as a soft-404 by search engines and just leaves users confused as to what they are now seeing. The redirection of "old" to "new" URLs (if the corresponding "new" URL exists on the new site) is an important part of a site relaunch - something which cannot be skipped. On the plus side, you _only_ have ">100" old pages.

Comment: Just 404 is not what the client prefers for these old pages that haven't been kept alive.
Routing is simple, there are physical folders and index.html files.
I'm aware of the SEO situation, I also told the client this. But they prefer just landing on the blog index page instead of a 404.

Comment: So the usual check whether what was requested does not match an existing folder (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`) should do the trick, no? If you want to do it from the root level, then just have the RewriteRule ensure that the path starts with `blog/` (and has anything after that, because you don't want to rewrite `blog/` itself as well.)

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to do that though, can anyone make an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your old page URLs were of the form `/blog/<old-page>/` and previously mapped to physical directories (from which a `DirectoryIndex` document was served) then you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(blog/)[^/]+/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

`$1` in the *substitution* string is a backreference to the first capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. “blog/“. This simply saves repetition.

*Aside:* Just to repeat the concern expressed in comments. With regards to SEO and users, this is likely worse than a custom 404 response that explains the absent page(s). Search engines will likely see this (a many to one redirect) as a soft-404 anyway and users are more likely to just be "confused" (and *bounce*) when they see different content to what they are expecting. There really is no substitute for "old" to "new" (one-to-one) 301 redirects.